# Overlapping transparency in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to make bezier curves with a nice glow/shadow in OpenGL ES 2. Everything is fine: I have a path made of many cubic beziers, each bezier being made of many traingles. Triangles, not lines, because lines can overlap and my triangles are put there according to the curve's derivative.(I can't explain better..I am not a native speaker, but I think you understand.) Each triangle have values on their vertices(0 or 1, depending on the side of the line a certain vertex is: right or left). This values get interpoleted and in the fragment shader the middle will have value 0.5. Based on this values, in the fragment shader, I decide if a certain pixel is on the line, or on the glow and I color it accordingly. Everything works fine, BUT I want to make the path split in 2. 
 [image]

As you see, the glow from the 2 lines overlap, making it look ugly. How can I fix it? Btw don't mind the bad quality(it's a screenshot zoomed) or the background.

Comment: Are you strictly limited to ES 2.0? I have an idea, but it unfortunately requires a feature that is only available in ES 3.0, or in an extensions.

Comment: Unfortunately yes..ES 3.0 is available from Android 4.3... This lower bound is too high I think. Half of the market doesn't have ES 3.0

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 possible ways to do that.

1. Stencil Buffer (Not sure if this is possible in ES so)

   - Draw non transparent objects.
   - Reset stencil buffer
   - Draw transparent objects only if stencil buffer == 0 and increment stencil buffer while drawing
2. Sorted depth

   - Give all transparent objects a different depth value
   - Draw transparent objects **Front to Back** with depth test enabled

Comment: About #2. Good idea! But atm I draw both the glow and the actual curve at once, the way you said I must draw them separately. I think it won't be a problem performance-wise, but still I will try to find a potentially better solution. But even with this solution I think artifacts will appear. Think about it. Still I will try it to se if it's better. I will investigate the stencil buffer and see what I find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet may be to hide the artifact. Since you are already adding custom per-vertex data for the interpolation, use another component that represents the t value at that vertex. In the fragment shader you can then do something with that value for these lines that split off.

For example since it appears you are using additive blending, for t=0 to 1, if you were to multiply the output color in the fragment shader by t, you would get a line that fades in across the entire length.

Obviously you wouldn't need the fade to last over the whole line, just until t=0.15 or something.  Map your value to 0..1 and this should effectively hide the double glow artifact.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but atm I don't hold any information about the curves splitting or not. I only know the 4 points that defines each curve. Not big deal to make anyways, but maybe it will be too much unnecessary load on the fragment shader for something so small and rare( I forgot to mention but the line will split like every 10 curves or so at most). Anyways, you got a good point. I will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: It should simply be just one additional instruction in the fragment program - a multiply to darken the color.If you compute the value in the vertex program, just pass in the darken factor as a varying.  Shouldn't be prohibitive to do all the time, even if the value is usually 1.0

Comment: You misunderstood something. The custom varrying I have atm is NOT the t of the curve, it's more like the width of the curve. So, firstly, I will need another varrying that will hold the t and put the instruction that you said. Secondly, I need to know if I should apply the fading to a certain curve (otherwise all the curves will have the fading, which is bad. Keep in mind that a long, curvy path is made from many bezier curves). In order to do that I will need to know if a curve have a twin (the curve is a splice). To be continued (out of character limit)

Comment: Other things that I need to take into account are the length of the curve and the "curviness" of the curve. The fading should last from 0 to 0.05(for example) on a long curve and from 0 to 0.1 on a short curve. And don't forget this will still give artifacts, but hopefully some that are harder to see. Anyways, all in all, with some work from the gpu this might solve the problem. :) Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I am definitely interested to see how you fix it!  More thoughts: 1) Presumably you're deciding to split curves on the CPU, if so, you can modify existing vertex data to pass in this color value. In fact, if you make it a generic color value and consider alpha as your fade factor, you can get some neat effects, and the vertex shader does almost no work too. 2) If concerned about adding another varying, pack it into your existing one (i.e. use a float2 instead of float) 3) You can do something similar with your existing width, by making the start of the curve very narrow when it's split.